# Unhandled Exception: [firebase_auth/unknown] null: Error in Phone Authentication using flutter/firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I have used this link as tutorial: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/phone/
But somehow, as I press the button I get this error:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_auth/unknown] null
E/flutter ( 6765): #0      MethodChannelFirebaseAuth.verifyPhoneNumber (package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase_auth.dart:583:7)
E/flutter ( 6765): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6765): #1      _OTPScreenState._verifyMyPhoneNumber (package:food_delivery_app/UIForAllCategory/PhoneAuth/OTPScreen.dart:41:5)
E/flutter ( 6765): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6765): 
D/ViewRootImpl[Toast]( 6765): hardware acceleration = true , fakeHwAccelerated = false, sRendererDisabled = false, forceHwAccelerated = false, sSystemRendererDisabled = false
```

I have enabled phone authentication at Firebase and as well redownloaded the GoogleServices file but facing this error consistently.
This is the first function that runs on the press of button:

```
  _verifyMyPhoneNumber() async {
    //This handler will only be called on Android devices which support automatic SMS code resolution.
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: '+92${this.widget.phoneNumber}',
        verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) async {
          await FirebaseAuth.instance
              .signInWithCredential(credential)
              .then((value) async {
            if (value.user != null) {
              //Change state and move to next Screen
              setState(() {
                this.widget.inProgress=false;
              });
              String myNumber=this.widget.phoneNumber;
              debugPrint("My number= $myNumber");
              prefs.setString("phone", "0$myNumber");

              //Getting values from preferences
              String number= prefs.getString("phone");
              String email=  prefs.getString("email");
              String username=  prefs.getString("username");
              String uid= prefs.getString("Gid");
              debugPrint("Details: $number, $email, $username,$uid");
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => EnteryPoint()),
              );
            }
          });
        },


        //In case, if Some error occured at Firebase then
        verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e) {

          //Change state and Go back with a prompt
          setState(() {
            this.widget.inProgress=false;
          });
          Fluttertoast.showToast(
              msg: "Error: $e",
              toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
              gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
              timeInSecForIosWeb: 2,
              backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
              textColor: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 12.0);
          Navigator.of(context).pop(); //Go back to previious screen
        },


        codeSent: (String verficationID, int resendToken) {
          debugPrint("Code is sent from Server, Soon you will recieve it");
          //Change state and Let user to enter the code when received
          setState(() {
            this.widget.inProgress=false;
          });
          Fluttertoast.showToast(
              msg: "Please wait, You will soon receive the code!",
              toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
              gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
              timeInSecForIosWeb: 2,
              backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
              textColor: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 12.0);
          setState(() {
            _verificationCode = verficationID;
          });
        },
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationID) {
          debugPrint("This device has not automatically resolved an SMS message within a certain Timeframe");
          setState(() {
            _verificationCode = verificationID;
          });
        },
        timeout: Duration(seconds: 60));
  }
```

Help please!

Comment: Did this issue resolved?

Comment: Well, yet the problem isn't solved.

Comment: Did you find solution?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you do have an instance of firebaseapp at the start of the program (main function).
Instance is created using await Firebase.initializeApp();

Your exception is the "instance of firebase_auth is null" and Firebase Auth doesn't work without firebaseapp.
Unhandled Exception: [firebase_auth/unknown] null

Comment: I've already used initFirebase() function that auto runs in the initState function of Splash screen. I think thats not the case as I have also tried to put await Firebase.initializeApp() in the _verifyPhoneNumber function too before getting firebase auth.

Comment: Are you sure that Firebase object has been initialised, I know that await is going to make the firebase.initialiseapp synchronous. I had a similar issue and turned out it was because the application started and used firebase core before the Initialisation so try initialising firebaseapp in your main.

Comment: I was sure about it. However, what I hadn't done was to close and uninstall the app from my physical device and redownloading the google-services file and replaced it with my previous one. Then I ran flutter clean and rebuilt the project. All worked fine. However thanks for your cooperation.

Answer (score 0):

Update "void main()" to "Future main()"

```
void main() async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
    runApp(MyApp());
}
```

**TO**

```
Future main() async {
   WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
   await Firebase.initializeApp(
   options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);// dont include "options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform" if you havn't used Flutter Fire
   runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
FirebaseAuth auth=FirebaseAuth.instance;
auth.userChanges();
auth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
//code`enter code here`
);
```

If you are trying to multiple login from one device

Answer (score -3):

Firebase has an auth attempt limit. Try again after a day.