# Firebase Authentication via OpenID Connect in Flutter apps

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, keycloak, openid-connect

I’m trying Firebase authentication via OIDC (Using Keycloak Provider) from my Flutter app like this:

```
await Firebase.initializeApp();
OAuthCredential oAuthCredential = OAuthProvider(Constants.PROVIDER_ID).credential(idToken: idToken);
try {
  UserCredential userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(oAuthCredential);
  debugPrint("UID: ${userCredential.user?.uid}");
} 
catch(e) {
  debugPrint("Error $e");
}
```

But Getting this:

```
Error [firebase_auth/unknown] null
```

About this error somebody suggested on this SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67850514/unhandled-exception-firebase-auth-unknown-null-error-in-phone-authentication) the issue can be because firebase not initialising
So i check using `Firebase.apps.length` But, Its initialising.

Am I missing something or firebase doesn’t provide this for Flutter?

**Updated:**

As suggested by @Bart Cone `signInWithProvider` is working fine in Android but in iOS app is crashing with the below error log:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                         0x10dd4d89b __exceptionPreprocess + 226
1   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x10548bba3 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                         0x10dd4d789 -[NSException initWithCoder:] + 0
3   FirebaseAuth                           0x102b8fa07 -[FIROAuthProvider getCredentialWithUIDelegate:completion:] + 167 (FIROAuthProvider.m:160)
4   Runner                                 0x101b13953 -[FLTFirebaseAuthPlugin signInWithProvider:withMethodCallResult:] + 851 (FLTFirebaseAuthPlugin.m:682)
5   Runner                                 0x101b0ef6c -[FLTFirebaseAuthPlugin handleMethodCall:result:] + 4092 (FLTFirebaseAuthPlugin.m:247)
6   Flutter                                0x115aa513d __45-[FlutterMethodChannel setMethodCallHandler:]_block_invoke + 168
7   Flutter                                0x11503a748 invocation function for block in flutter::PlatformMessageHandlerIos::HandlePlatformMessage(std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::unique_ptr<flutter::PlatformMessage, std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::default_delete<flutter::PlatformMessage> >) + 94
8   libdispatch.dylib                      0x10b86f7fb _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
9   libdispatch.dylib                      0x10b870a3a _dispatch_client_callout + 8
10  libdispatch.dylib                      0x10b88032c _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 1338
11  libdispatch.dylib                      0x10b87fde4 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 31
12  CoreFoundation                         0x10dcacb1f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
13  CoreFoundation                         0x10dca7436 __CFRunLoopRun + 2482
14  CoreFoundation                         0x10dca66a7 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 560
15  GraphicsServices                       0x10c20c28a GSEventRunModal + 139
16  UIKitCore                              0x128396ad3 -[UIApplication _run] + 994
17  UIKitCore                              0x12839b9ef UIApplicationMain + 123
18  Runner                                 0x101a3ea3f main + 63 (AppDelegate.swift:5)
19  dyld_sim                               0x101eba2bf start_sim + 10
20  dyld                                   0x10e3f952e start + 462

Thread 0 Crashed::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Flutter `firebase_auth` package does support this but the docs are lacking an example.

Assuming you have upgraded to use Identity Platform, create your OIDC provider and make sure you choose `Code flow`. You can reference the iOS section if needed (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/openid-connect).

Once that's configured, grab the `Provider ID` that's generated. It will look something like `oidc.sample-integration`.

Now in your flutter application the following code is all you need to kick off the sign-in process.

```
final provider = OAuthProvider('oidc.sample-integration');
await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithProvider(provider)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have already configured my provider on Firebase and generated the provider id, But not tried with signInWithProvider() method before, It's working now.

Comment: But I'm getting accessToken as null using userCredential.credential?.accessToken and refreshToken as nothing using userCredential.user?.refreshToken ?

Comment: I think I saw your google group post and the implicit flow was selected - I would change that to code flow on the FB side and also update your flow on the keycloak side to be auth code. Authorization code flow is the correct flow when using an auth broker like Firebase auth.

Comment: One other thing -- there's actually two different tokens that will be minted. The token you're trying to access in your example above (`userCredential.credential`) is the raw access token from the IdP (keycloak in your case). I would be surprised if you're wanting this one. The other minted token is from Firebase itself. It's accessed via `userCredential.user?.getIdToken()` -- this token is the one that can be verified with the firebase admin sdk, in say, node land.

Comment: Yes, I need the IdP access token and refresh token, Seems firebase will not provide these it provides only idToken, So now I'm getting this from Keycloak and then calling signInWithProvider for Firebase auth.

Comment: signInWithProvider is working as expected in Android But in iOS app crashing with this?

Comment: Not sure without more information. I would check that you have the iOS app configured correctly (plist file etc).

Comment: Hi @Bart Cone, I'm using CFBundleURLSchemes in my plist and also added entitlement in iOS app, What I need apart from this?  I added a crash log also with the question.